# How to recognize hover/click of a border in CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am working on a CodePen to make a draggable and resizavle box without Jquery. What I am trying to accomplish is that when you hover/click over the main body of the div you can drag it around and will have the "move" cursor.

When you hover/click on the border, you can resize the box, based on which side you click on and have the "col-resize" or "row-resize" cursor.

What I am really wondering is if it is even possible to select the border with JS and CSS, and if so how.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your CodePen?

Comment: It is possible, when you make your element unique in some way and then use it in the jQuery selector

Comment: You have to calculate how far is from the border or use transparent divs as borders.

Comment: @ChrisHappy https://codepen.io/TheAndersMan/pen/KmNoPR?editors=1111 sorry every time I try to it tells me I can't. Pretty annoying.

Comment: @ChrisHappy sorry, I meant that when I type my question in, it won't let me publish my question if I have a link to a CodePen in it.

Comment: No worries @TheAndersMan! You just have to add some code if you want to link to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an example of how to determine which border you're hovering (good luck with your other calculations):

```js
var div = document.querySelector("#div");
var delta = 10; // the thickness of the hovered border area

div.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.clientX - rect.left,      // the relative mouse postion to the element
        y = e.clientY - rect.top,       // ...
        w = rect.right - rect.left,     // width of the element
        h = rect.bottom - rect.top;     // height of the element
        
   var c = "";                          // which cursor to use
   if(y < delta) c += "n";              // north
   else if( y > h - delta) c += "s";    // south
   if(x < delta) c += "w";              // west
   else if(x > w - delta) c += "e";     // east
   
   if(c)                                // if we are hovering at the border area (c is not empty)
       div.style.cursor = c + "-resize"; // set the according cursor
   else                                 // otherwise
       div.style.cursor = "pointer";    // set to pointer
}
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<br>Psst! Hover at the border area! Corners too.
```

**Note:** The above method doesn't relly on wether or not the element has borders, and wether or not it could have child nodes (for example `img`...).

Comment: If you want to click on the borders, just add `box-sizing: border-box` to the element and make delta the width of the borders.

Comment: `var x = e.clientX - rect.left` can be written shorter with `var x = e.offsetX`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I don't think that you can detect a click just on the border without any workaround. You could detect the border by checking where the mouse is in relation to box, as @ibrahim mahrir did, but I prefer just using a wrapper element it:</sub>

**Undynamic to CSS values**

The most simple. Set the width of the "border" manually. Use if you're never going to change the padding/width of the "border".

```js
var border = document.getElementById("border");

var bor = 4;

border.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
  console.log("border-clicked")
}

border.onmouseover = function(e) {
  y = e.offsetY;
  
  if (y <= bor || y >= this.offsetHeight - bor) c = "row"
  else c = "col"

  this.style.cursor = c + "-resize";
}
```

```css
#border {
  padding: 4px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic to one CSS value**

Set the width of the "border" by selecting one of the values of the padding. Use this if are going to change the value of the padding and has the same width throughout.

```js
var border = document.getElementById("border");

var bor = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(border, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left') )

border.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
  console.log("border-clicked")
}

border.onmouseover = function(e) {
  y = e.offsetY;
  
  if (y <= bor || y >= this.offsetHeight - bor) c = "row"
  else c = "col"

  this.style.cursor = c + "-resize";
}
```

```css
#border {
  padding: 4px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic to both CSS values**

Set the width of the "border" by selecting a horizontal and vertical value of the padding. Use this if the padding is like `padding: #px #px`.

```js
var border = document.getElementById("border");


var borderStyles = window.getComputedStyle(border, null);
var borLeft = parseInt( borderStyles.getPropertyValue('padding-left') )
var borTop = parseInt( borderStyles.getPropertyValue('padding-top') )

border.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
  console.log("border-clicked")
}

border.onmouseover = function(e) {
  x = e.offsetX;
  y = e.offsetY;
  
 if (x < borLeft || x > this.offsetWidth - borLeft ) c = "col";
 else if (y <= borTop || y >= this.offsetHeight - borTop) c = "row"

  this.style.cursor = c + "-resize";
}
```

```css
#border {
  padding: 4px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The whole point of my answer is that it can be done without any actuall borders.

Comment: How would you determine which cursor to use?

Comment: But this won't be practical as it doesn't tell wether you're `col-resizing` or `row-resizing` which OP asked for (_... and have the "col-resize" or "row-resize" cursor_).

Comment: Okay, I got it! What do you think @ibrahimmahrir?

Answer (score 0):

Create a div and make it is position absolute inside your hole div add the style of you border to it then give a hover effect and the event you want to it.
Set the position relative to the hole div and absolute to the border div you have to set left, right,top,bottom to minus value according to your border width you may need to make the background-color as transparent.